# Contradictory differentiability of $z^{-1}$ and $\frac{1}{z}$ in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

In complex analysis. We know $f(z) = \frac{1}z$ is analytical everywhere except $z \neq 0$. However, if we consider $f(z) = \frac{1}z = z^{-1} $, by viewing $z^{-1}$ as **the** branch of multivalue function $z^{-1}$. Where complex power is considered as follows:

$$z^w=\exp(w\ln|z|+iw\arg(z)+2iw\pi k)$$

Note that $z^n$ has its usual meaning when $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. So $z^{-1} = \{\exp(-1\ln|z| -i\arg(z))\} = \{\frac{1}z\}$.

We know $z^{-1}$ is only analytical on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, 0]$. **EDIT: This statement is wrong, although we can conclude that for a branch of a general complex power function $f(z)= z^w$ is analytical on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, 0]$ by proof, it doesn't preclude the possibility that it can be differentiable on $(-\infty, 0]$. See answers.**

What's wrong with the reasoning?

Comment: Why would $z^{-1}$ be multivalued? $z^n$ is not multivalued if $n\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Wait, how is $z^{-1}$ multi-valued? Complex analysis is not my area, so I could be very wrong here, but even interpreting it as $\exp(-\ln(z))$ is still single-valued in the end. What are the other branches of $z^{-1}$?

Comment: True, $z^{-1}$ has its usual meaning. I have corrected this mistake.

Comment: $e^{2\pi ik}  = 1$ if $k\in \mathbb Z$. Thus $z^{-1} =w^{-1}$ if $|z|=|w|$ and $\arg z = \arg w \pmod{2\pi}$, i.e., there is no multivaluedness.

Comment: Are you saying that, because $z^{-1}$ can be interpreted as the composition of an analytic function ($z \mapsto e^{-z}$) and a set-valued function, whose principal branch is only analytic on $\Bbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, 0]$ ($\ln$), the resulting single-valued function ought to be only analytic on $\Bbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, 0]$?

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes that's exactly what I am confused about. There is another interpretation here.

Comment: @Beginner I guess the answer is, "this is not a valid form of reasoning, as this example demonstrates". While composition of two functions like this will ensure that the result is analytic on the intersection of their domains, it does not preclude the result being analytic on a larger set. A simpler example: we can compose a constant function with any function (on the left or right), which could be analytic (or not) on one of many weird and wonderful subsets of $\Bbb{C}$, but the result of composition is constant, which is analytic everywhere.

Comment: Sorry, there's an embarrassing flub in my (otherwise useful) comment above. You don't just intersect the domains, the domain on which you can guarantee analyticity of $f \circ g$ would be $\operatorname{dom} g \cap g^{-1}(\operatorname{dom} f)$. Still, my point stands: this is just a set on which analyticity is guaranteed, but this doesn't stop the function from being analytic on a larger domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\Log{\operatorname{Log}}$

The definition of $z^w$ is $e^{w \Log z}$ and the "multivaluation" comes from the fact that $\Log z = \log|z|+(\arg z+2\pi k)i$ with $k \in \Bbb Z$.

In the case of $w=-1$ we have

\begin{align}z^{-1} =  e^{-\Log z} & = e^{-(\log |z| +(\arg z +2\pi k)i)} \\
&= e^{-\log |z|-i \arg z-i2\pi k}\\
&= e^{-\log |z|-i \arg z}e^{-i2\pi k}\\
&= e^{-\log |z|-i \arg z}
\end{align}

because $e^{-i2\pi k} = 1$ for all $k \in \Bbb Z$, so $z^{-1}$ has only one branch, so it's not really multivalued.

Edit: I see now that what's troubling you is that you are under the impression that if $g$ is not differentiable and $f$ is differentiable, then $f\circ g$ can't be differentiable.

$|z|$ is not differentiable, $\arg z$ is not differentiable, but $|z| e^{i\arg z}=z$ is differentiable.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But how about the differentiability of $z^{-1}$, we know $arg z$ is not even continuous on $(-\infty, 0]$

Comment: The fact that $\arg z$ is not differentiable doesn't mean that $e^{-\log |z| - i \arg z}$ can't be differentiable. (In fact, it is, because it's equal to $1/z$)

Comment: $|z|$ is not differentiable, $\arg z$ is not differentiable, but $|z| e^{i \arg z} = z$ is differentiable

Comment: Yes, I think this answered my question, you could add this example to your answer if you don't mind.

Comment: I see now that what's troubling you is that you are under the impression that if $g$ is not differentiable and $f$ is differentiable, then $f\circ g$ can't be differentiable.

Answer (score 3):

Even if $\log z$ is discontinuous, it does not follow that $e^{-\log z}$ is discontinuous.  [The converse of a true implication may or may not be true—in this case, not.]

Similarly: $\sqrt{z}$ is discontinuous on $(-\infty,0)$; but, even so, $(\sqrt{z}\;)^2$ is continuous there.